# Haskell errors: "lacks an accompanying binding" and "not in scope"

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I have created a piece of code this:

```
intToDigit :: Char -> Int
ord :: Char -> Int
intToDigit c = ord c - ord 'a'
```

However, when I run it I get this error message:

> ChangeVowels.hs:2:1:
>       The type signature for `ord' lacks an accompanying binding
>
> ChangeVowels.hs:4:16: Not in scope: `ord'
>
> ChangeVowels.hs:4:24: Not in scope: `ord'

I tried it with `Import data.char` but that doesnt work either.

Comment: Note that capitalisation is important: your import line should be `import Data.Char` (or perhaps `import Data.Char hiding (intToDigit)`).

Comment: @Dave or better, `import Data.Char (ord)`

Comment: Also if you incidentally lowercase your function name so you have intToDigit in type declaration and inttodigit in implementation you will get lacks an accompanying yada yada. I learned the hard way...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to provide an implementation for the function `ord`. *Here, you have given a signature for `ord`, but no implementation.*

Or you can use Haskell's own `ord` function, that is `Char.ord`.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the line:

```
ord :: Char -> Int
```

Or give it a definition.

And it's a bad idea to name your function intToDigit, while it's already used in Data.Char to do the opposite of what you are doing.

Your function is Data.Char.digitToInt, and its implementation also works with hexadecimal:

```
digitToInt :: Char -> Int
digitToInt c
 | isDigit c            =  ord c - ord '0'
 | c >= 'a' && c <= 'f' =  ord c - ord 'a' + 10
 | c >= 'A' && c <= 'F' =  ord c - ord 'A' + 10
 | otherwise            =  error ("Char.digitToInt: not a digit " ++ show c) -- sigh
```

Actually it's not what you defined... why `'a'` in your code?